# how to set button size in inches in android

Tags: android, button, size

how to set button size in inches in android?

I want to set button size in inches according to the device screen size. It means I want to set in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library called  [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) where it helps you most of the time.

This android lib that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

Lastly inches are not recommended for design. for more details follow this link
https://material.io/design/layout/understanding-layout.html